# How can i upload files that containing inside json object with retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have this json structure

```
"documents": {
0: {
    "title": 'Some title',
    "type": 4,
    "file": file,
},
1: {
    "title": 'Some title',
    "description": 'Some description',
    "type": 3,
    "file": file,
},
"someKey": {
    "title": 'Some title',
    "description": 'Some description',
    "type": 3,
    "file": file,
}}
```

how can i upload files to server with this json structure?

Comment: What you want please elaborate clearly

Comment: You need to represent binary data in a string. you should use base64

Comment: @AnubhavGupta I want send image file, that will inside in json object, but this json object will be part of map, sorry, I'm not very good in English

Comment: @akaki thx, but I can have more images, and if I will represent them like string, I think, I can catch oom

Comment: @ВалерийСетраков from what I understood you want to upload an image in JSON format. Is that correct? If that's the case, then one of the possible solutions is to do what akaki said, i.e. to encode it in Base64 and decode it on server side